# How do I get symmetric key generated in SSL handshake?

Tags: java, ssl, https, tomcat8, jsse

> During SSL handshake the client encrypts generated pre-master secret
>   with the server's public key and sends to the server. Both Server and
>   Client perform steps to generate the master secret with the agreed
>   cipher. Both the client and the server use the master secret to
>   generate the session keys,  which are **symmetric keys** used to
>   encrypt and decrypt information exchanged during the SSL session
>
> http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-does-ssl-work-what-ssl-handshake

How do I get that symmetric key, so that I can store that into database and use the same every time client connects?

Both the server and client should save that key and never do handshaking process again. Next time(even after disconnecting) they should directly start the communication using symmetric key over https.

In short, I want SSL session to last forever.

**EDIT**
Android device is the client. Client-Server exchange only few bytes data whenever client gets online. SSL is overhead in this case, isnt it ?

Comment: Generally a bad idea. Ever lasting sessions with reused keys are bad practice as you can over long time get into the connection. And what are you connecting to? Where are you connecting from? Which exact protocol are you using?

Comment: That will not work, you can only use an SSL session cache, however if the client does not send you the old session ID a new session have to be created. That is the way it is specified by SSL/TLS - if you don't want it this way you can not use SSL/TLS.

Comment: If all you need is a shared symmetric key just generate one on the client and send it to the other side over the SSL connection. There is really nothing to be fined by using the symmetric key generated by the SSL session.

Comment: @zaph Then that is not called https...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I get that symmetric key

You can't in Java.

> so that I can store that into database and use the same every time client connects?

You can't in SSL.

> Both the server and client should save that key and never do handshaking process again.

You can't. It would be insecure.

> Next time(even after disconnecting) they should directly start the communication using symmetric key over https.

You can't.

> In short, I want SSL session to last forever.

You can't, and you don't want to. It would be insecure.

> SSL is overhead in this case, isnt it?

Such questions are meaningless. Compared to what? You can't compare a secure solution to an insecure solution. If you don't want security, don't use SSL.

Comment: Thanks letting me know this is impossible with SSL. How it would be insecure to save key for future communication, if the client is not a browser but a closed source program ? ;)

Comment: Because the symmetric key isn't long enough to be secure indefinitely. The problem you're trying to solve doesn't really exist. SSL session resumption does work and allows for numerous session keys within the same session without complete rehandshakes.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: "How do I get that symmetric key, so that I can store that into database and use the same every time client connects?".

If all you need is a shared symmetric key just generate one on the client and send it to the other side over the SSL connection. There is really nothing to be gained by using the symmetric key generated by the SSL session.

What is the difference between using the symmetric key generated by SSL and one generated by you?

Also when using TLS 1.2 and perfect forward secrecy the symmetric key used is not the one generated by the client in the initial exchange but one generated using Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE-RSA, ECDHE-ECDSA).

Answer (score 1):

You can not. The negotiated key should be private. For reference I send you the link to the apache environment variables. You will see that the symmetric key is not one of them

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html

You can get the sessionID, but how to reuse the sessions must be left to the SSL / TLS protocol. It has automatic renegotiation options so you can reuse the session, even if the server has already discarded. The protocol will decide when you can or can not reuse.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746

Comment: The Apache HTTPD mod_ssl environment variables don't have anything to do with what is available from inside a Java application. As a matter of fact Apache HTTPD mod_ssl uses OpenSSL, which *does* make the session key available. But it isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: mod_ssl is an example used to show that the symmetric key is not available in a well-known software

Comment: And OpenSSL is an example used to show that it is available in another piece of well-known software. So? The question is about **Java.**

Comment: ok, you are right, as @Nilesh does not indicate that use a proxy like apache, what is important is to know which SSL variables provides TOMCAT8 to the java server

Comment: So it wasn't provided as an example but as a guess as to the OP's configuration? In any case it is also important to know what the Java API provides. Both sides need the key in the OP's scheme.